# PHP Count how many times a specific word shows up in h3 tag

Tags: php

I need to be able to count how many times a specific word shows up in a specific html tag. Currently I have only been able to count the total number of words that show up in a tag. And I can count how many times the word shows up total in the document, but I cant figure out how to count how many times a word shows up just in the h3 tag for example.

Example of what I need:

```
Sample text here, blah blah blah, lorem ipsum
<h3>Lorem is in this h3 tag, lorem.</h3>
lorem ipsum dolor....
<h3>This is another h2 with lorem in it</h3>
```

So as you see the word "lorem" is in that code 4 times, but I only want to count how many times the word "lorem" shows up in the h3 tag's.

I would prefer to keep using PHP on this project.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Use DOM to access elements in an HTML document.

Comment: .. And use [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a regular expression to do this:

```
<?php
    $string = 'Sample text here, blah blah blah, lorem ipsum
    <h3>Lorem is in this h3 tag, lorem.</h3>
    lorem ipsum dolor....
    <h3>This is another h2 with lorem in it</h3>';

     preg_match_all("/lorem(?=(?:.(?!<h3>))*<\/h3>)/i", $string, $matches);

     if (isset($matches[0])) {
        $count = count($matches[0]);
     } else {
        $count = 0;
     }

?>
```

Comment: That seems to just always return a "2" no matter how many times lorem is included in the h3

Comment: The regex has been updated to match multiple occurrences of a word inside each tag.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) like this:

```
$string = 'Sample text here, blah blah blah, lorem ipsum
<h3>Lorem is in this h3 tag, lorem.</h3>
lorem ipsum dolor....
<h3>This is another h2 with lorem in it</h3>';

$html = new DOMDocument(); // create new DOMDocument
$html->loadHTML($string);  // load HTML string
$cnt = array();           // create empty array for words count
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('h3') as $one){ // loop in each h3
    $words = str_word_count(strip_tags($one->nodeValue), 1, '0..9'); // count words including numbers
    foreach($words as $wo){ // create an key for every word 
        if(!isset($cnt[$wo])){ $cnt[$wo] = 0; } // create key if it doesn't exit add 0 as word count
        $cnt[$wo]++; // increment it's value each time it's repeated - this will result in the word having count 1 on first loop
    }
}


var_export($cnt); // dump words and how many it repeated
```